Capture mobile image and save it on the server
I'm using dot NET and I want to capture an image from a mobile device like iPhone to save the captured Image.
I tried used this command as HTML:
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" > 


What is the equivalent in ASP.NET?
I got the image but I need to know how to upload it on the server such as: "http://10.0.0.146/info/images/testweb.png"

